# multiple belongs_to for a model

Tags: activerecord, belongs-to

I have this model "Comment" which is given by a model "User" for a given "city" and "department".
While creating the schema for table "comments", I put in columns city_id, department_id and user_id which should act as foreign keys to respective ids in tables cities, departments and users.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :department    
end
```

Cities and Departments are independent tables which are populated with reference data (which would be used to populate  in the forms.

When I try to access comment.city.name, I get a "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".
Table cities is defined with columns -"id", "name" and "symbol". 
What is the root cause of this error?
What else do I need to do ? I have tried even by putting has_many :feedbacks in class City and class Department (even though it should not happen because they are independent of comments). I am missing something basic here, it seems.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a has_many to go with every belongs_to. So each of your classes that comments belong_to (User, City, Department) should have

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I have already tried that out. I have had a matching of has_many :comments in three models - User, City, Department. The table Comments already has the columns user_id, city_id, department_id. The table comments already has the data populated while creating a new comment - ids of person, city and department. But while viewing the data, I want corresponding names to be displayed instead of ids. Thats when I am trying to do comment.user.name and it fails.

Comment: Ok, that's good! I think it might help if you post the relevant parts of schema.rb in case there is something weird in that. Another thing to try forcing rails to access the objects in the correct order: (comment.city).name (don't know why but sometimes rails needs to be told exactly how to do it)